# insert data into table when no_data_found or dup_val_on_index then do not insert

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I want to insert data into a table.

```
 create table test_a (svc_id, ent_id, val);


insert into table test_a (10060, 84181, Cartoon_Network);

insert into table test_a (30064, 84181, Cartoon_Network);

insert into table test_a (322648, 84181, 93);

insert into table test_a(359668, 84181, 45);

insert into table test_a(316280, 84181, 93);

insert into table test_a(316279,84181,161);
```

using this data i need to check values of VAL column into another table like :-

```
create table ref_data(ref_cd varchar2(50), ref_desc varchar2(50));
```

All column are not null in test_a table;

```
insert into ref_data values(Cartoon_Network, Cartoon_Network_desc);

insert into ref_data values(93, NET Facil HD );

insert into ref_data values(45, 6 Estrelas);
```

Now we have our data through which i need to populate the test_a table again with

`ent_id = 84182` (hardcoded)

and the VAL column will be the value -

```
select ref_desc from ref_data where ref_cd = (val from the test_a column for each sub_id)
```

So here we have all values now to insert a new row into test_a;

Here we have to check if no data found then no rows should be inserted or if dup_val_on_index then also no should inserted.

i write a code like

```
declare

cursor c_test is select * from test_a;

l_rec c_test%rowtype;

l_ent    number := 84182;

l_desc  varchar2(50);

begin

open c_test;

loop

fetch c_test into l_rec;

begin

select ref_desc into l_desc from ref_data where ref_cd = l_rec.val;

insert into test_a values (l_rec.sub_id, l_ent, l_desc);

exception

when no_data_found then

  null;

when dup_val_on_index then

 null;

end;

exit when c_test%notfound;

end loop;

exception

when others then

dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode||' '||sqlerrm);

end;
```

but this code is not working as per my expectation.

DATABASE version :

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Go read about the MERGE statement.

Comment: Yes merge option is good here but as the tables and data here i provide is only sample data. In real i need to fetch data from about 5-6 table to validate like sub_id, ent_id and then ref_cd. So here i thiknk MERGE will not work?

Comment: If you want us to provide a solution you must provide *a realistic explanation* of your scenario.  It's no good posting something simplistic and then responding to suggestions with "oh but my actual situation is too complicated for that to work".  Reduce your case to its necessary  minimum level of complexity and post that here.  Otherwise you're just wasting everybody's time, including your's.

Comment: Is this code compiled properly? Not sure why EXCEPTION block is included twice? What error are you getting?